# Error: The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, vue.js, axios

I am trying to retrieve data from the api I made with nodejs/fastifyjs. I am able to get data from the api without errors but when I try to post request I get the error in the browser console of character encoding although I have specified the charset meta tag. When I send post request from postman I get proper response and data gets saved. Here is the frontend code I am using ...

Also when I try to send data from postman I select the x-www-urlformencoded option because when I use form-data option I get error code "405".

[image: This is the error I get inside the console when I make the post request]

The html5 document code ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{msg}}
        <button v-on:click="getData">Get Data</button>
        <div v-for="detail in details">
            <br>
            <span>Name : {{detail.name}}</span><br>
            <span>Age : {{detail.age}}</span><br>
            <span>Image : {{detail.imageUrl}}</span><br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="sendDataToServer">
            <form method="post">
                <span>Enter Name: <input type="text" v-model="name"></span><br>
                <span>Enter Age: <input type="number" v-model="age"></span><br>
                <span>Enter Image url: <input type="text" v-model="imageUrl"></span><br>
                <button v-on:click="sendData">Save data</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>Screenshot from 2019-03-17 16-11-42
```

The Vue Code I use to get and post data with axios ...

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',

    data:{
        msg: 'VueJS!',
        details: [],
        name:'',
        age: 0,
        imageUrl:'',
    },

    methods:{
        getData: function () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/getData')
            .then((result) => {
                this.details = result.data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },

        sendData: function(){
            let config = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            axios.post('http"localhost:3000/saveData',{
                name: this.name,
                age: this.age,
                imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
            }, config)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },


    }
})
```

The api code is here ...

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
    logger:{
        prettyPrint: true
    }
});

// Requiring the model
const dbSch = require('./models')

// Requiring Cors
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'))

// Requiring to get data from incoming request body
fastify.register(require('fastify-formbody'))

// ******
// Defining ROUTES
// ******

fastify.get('/', (request, reply)=>{
    reply.send('Hello Fastify')
})

fastify.get('/getData', (request, reply) => {
    dbSch.find({}).exec(function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err
        // let resultObj = JSON.parse(result)
        reply.send(result)
    })
})

fastify.post('/saveData', (request, reply) => {
    let saveDataTodb = new dbSch({
        name: request.body.name,
        age: request.body.age,
        imageUrl: request.body.imageUrl,
    })

    saveDataTodb.save(function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            console.log('saved !!!')
            // reply.header('Content-Type', 'text/json')
            reply.send('Saved to DB')
        }
    })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

fastify.listen(port)
```

Comment: Not sure it'd be the source of the issue, but you have a typo: `axios.post('http"localhost...` should be `axios.post('http://localhost...`.

Comment: It appears to be the same problem even after correcting the typo!